# The equivalence between Smith Normal Form over PID and the structure theorem of free module 's submodule

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

In my algebra book the author claims the equivalence between following two theorems but doesn't say why.

> Theorem 1 Let M be a free module of rank *m* over a PID, N is a submodule of M. Then there exists a basis {$e_1$,...,$e_m$} of M such that {$d_1e_1$,...,$d_re_r$} is a basis of N and $d_i$|$d_{i+1}$.
>
> Theorem 2 (Smith Normal Form) Let A be a $m\times n$-matrix over a PID, then A is equivalent to
> \begin{bmatrix} d_1 & 0 &0 &0 &... \\
> 0 &d_2 &0 &0 &... \\
> 0 &0 &d_3 &0 &... \\
> ...
> \end{bmatrix}
> where $d_i$|$d_{i+1}$.

My attempt: ($\Rightarrow$) Let A=($t_{ij}$) as in theorem 2, {$a_1$,...,$a_m$} be a basis of M, suppose $f_i$=$\sum_{j=0}^m$$t_{ji}$$a_j$ and N is a submodule generated by $f_1,...,f_n$. Theorem 1 tells us that there exists a basis {$e_1$,...,$e_m$} of M such that {$d_1e_1$,...,$d_re_r$} is a basis of N, thus we have an invertible matrix $P$ such that ($a_1$,...,$a_m$)=($e_1$,...,$e_m$)$P$ and a matrix $Q$ such that ($f_1,...,f_n$)=($d_1e_1$,...,   $d_re_r$,0,...0)$Q$ (clearly $r\le n$). If $Q$ is invertible, then we can conclude that ($d_1e_1$,...,$d_re_r$,0,...0)=($e_1$,...,$e_m$)$PAQ^{-1}$. A simple calculation shows that $PAQ^{-1}$ is in Smith normal form. However, I don't think that's always true that $Q$ is invertible so this proof does not work.

Besides, I think the proof of "$\Leftarrow$" can be done in a similar way but again I get lost.

Any hints or helps will be appreciated. By the way, are there some textbooks or lecture notes that give a detailed proof of my problem? I think that's an important result.(Maybe too trivial?) Thank you in advance.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1441046/118955

Comment: @MarcBogaerts But my question is about the submodules of a free module, seems a bit different. Maybe it can be proved by the same method as in that question, but I can't write down the details...